# react native copilot infinite rerenders when launching

Tags: reactjs, native

I am using the react-native-copilot for making a walkthrough for my application. It is working when I launch it with a button, but I would like that it launches automatically when the user opens the app

I have done several attempts also including a timer but I always get infinite rerenders... Does anybody have any idea why their are infinite rerenders and how I could solve it? Thank you very much

```
const myScreen = props => {
  const handleStartButtonPress = () => {
     props.start();
  }

  const [startTutorial, setStartTutorial] = useState(true);

  if(showTutorial) {
      handleStartButtonPress();
  }
  setStartTutorial(false);
```

I also tried with useEffect and it works but only without the if check, if I add the if check it doesn't work

```
const [showTutorial, setShowTutorial] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    if(showTutorial) {
        props.start();
    }
}, [showTutorial]);

setShowTutorial(false);
```

Comment: Try useEffect(()=>{ .... },[])

Comment: I just tried to do it with useEffect and it works without the if check but if I add the if check again there are too many rerenders. I have added it to the original question

Comment: showTutorial must be a state, then useEffect on it with [showTutorial]

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it but I still get the same problem, I updated my question. I included the [showTutorial]. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok instead of using a state, it worked with a variable from the store! Thanks for helping me solve my problem!